# How to add contentRoot to build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

So I been searching around and couldn't find an answer to this.

Right now, to add a resource folder to my project, I have to go to File > Project Structure > Modules > Add Content Root

But the problem is, after I restart Intellij, I have to redo the process again.

The folder that I load is off a network drive.

How would I get this done via build.gradle?

Comment: Copy the resources where they should be, i.e. inside the project?

Comment: I can't copy it as its coming from a network Drive which is shared. The project itself I pulled from Subversion to my C Drive, and that content root folder needs to be included when it runs through build.gradle. If it was as easy as copying and pasting, I would have done it already.

Comment: It *is* as easy. The statically bundled resources of a project should live in the project itself, and thus be in your Subversion repo, just as the rest of the code of your project, instead of being shared using a network drive.